# Editing function.php from a custom plugin in WordPress. Line of code prohibiting certain core functions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm pretty new to coding and I just took over a WordPress site where the developer set up their own plugin to edit the functions.php file outside the theme. There seems to be a line of code that is breaking certain core functions in WordPress such as: installing new plugins are failing, cannot search for themes, and the media library is not loading. But if I deactivate this plugin all of these functions come back to life but then some parts of the sites layout break without the plugin on. So can anyone tell me how to fix this code? Thank you so much in advance.

```
<?php
/* Your code goes below here. */

ob_start();
function check_user_logged_in(){

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
#theme-my-login-2 .widget-wrap .widget-title { display: block !important; }
</style>
<?php
}
else{ ?>
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
table.sidebar_result{margin-top:-10px;}
</style>
<?php
}
}

// Something is wrong with this next line of code. Can't find new themes or install new plugins. When removed everthing works ok.
add_action('init', 'check_user_logged_in');

// Add Read More Link to Excerpts
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'get_read_more_link');
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'get_read_more_link' );
function get_read_more_link() {
return '...&nbsp;<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Read&nbsp;More]</a>';
}

//* Display a custom favicon
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_load_favicon', 'sp_favicon_filter' );
function sp_favicon_filter( $favicon_url ) {
return 'http://winningsportsplays.com/wspwp/wp-content/favicon.ico';
}

/* Your code goes above here. */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks fine to me as it is. My guess is that initializing the function through 'init' is somehow causing a conflict with some of the core files.

Trying changing this:

```
add_action('init', 'check_user_logged_in');
```

To this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'check_user_logged_in');
```

And see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The "init" is the problem for sure but your suggestion breaks the styling of parts on the page. The problem seems to be the function is applying to the admin or dashboard section and breaking it.

Comment: If the problem is it's just breaking the admin area but fine elsewhere, then using if (!is_admin()) {} as you suggested should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `if (!is_admin()) {}` into the code seems to have worked but is it correct?

```
ob_start();
function check_user_logged_in(){
**if (!is_admin()) {**
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
#theme-my-login-2 .widget-wrap .widget-title { display: block !important; }
</style>
<?php
}
else{ ?>
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
table.sidebar_result{margin-top:-10px;}
</style>
<?php
}
**}**
}
```